# SQL Nested Selects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is a better way to do the nested `select`s so that the firstname and surname is only doing one `select` (but still returning 2 fields) - something like a `join` with a `where` clause in it that only returns the first matching object.

```
SELECT
    w.[RECID],
    w.[PERSONNELNUMBER],
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            [FIRSTNAME]
        FROM [dbo].[DIRPERSONNAME] AS d
        WHERE d.PERSON = w.PERSON
    ) AS FirstName,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            LASTNAME
        FROM [dbo].[DIRPERSONNAME] AS d
        WHERE d.PERSON = w.PERSON
    ) AS Surname,
    u.[USER_] AS UserName,
    l.[LOCATOR] AS Email,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            ed.MARHRSTRUCTUREID AS Structure
        FROM [dbo].[HCMEMPLOYMENT] AS e
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MARHCMEMPDETAILS] AS ed ON e.RECID = ed.EMPLOYMENT
        WHERE e.Worker = w.RECID
    ) AS Structure
FROM
    [dbo].[DIRPARTYTABLE] AS p
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[HCMWORKER] AS w ON w.PERSON = p.RECID
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DIRPERSONUSER] AS u ON w.PERSON = u.PERSONPARTY
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS] AS l ON l.RECID = p.PRIMARYCONTACTEMAIL
```

Comment: will this ever return a null for the `Structure` column?

Comment: Yes it can do, sorry didn't see your answer.  I'll check it now

Comment: if it will return null then I need to change my answer slightly, I was making some assumptions when I wrote the query.

Comment: does either the `FIRSTNAME` or `SURNAME` return null on occasion as well?

Comment: No, they should there, but there may be multipple entries in that DIRPERSONNAME table for the same person (these are AX tables which is why the structure is so poor)

Comment: can you post the Schema Diagram for all these tables? and the Keys for the `DIRPERSONNAME` table and the `HCMWORKER` table

Comment: I'll have a look at doing this tomorrow - finished for the day now and I want to make the most of the sunshine!  thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those nested select statements at all, you just need to join to the `DIRPERSONNAME` table on the Identifiers that you are already using from the other tables.

I also included `HCMEMPLOYMENT` and `MARHCMEMPDETAILS` linking `e.Worker` to `w.RECID`

This should be much more efficient.

```
SELECT w.[RECID]
    , w.[PERSONNELNUMBER]
    , d.[FIRSTNAME]
    , d.[SURNAME]
    , u.[USER_] AS UserName
    , l.[LOCATOR] AS Email
    , ed.MARHRSTRUCTUREID AS Structure
    FROM [dbo].[DIRPARTYTABLE] AS p
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[HCMWORKER] AS w ON w.PERSON = p.RECID
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DIRPERSONNAME] AS d ON d.PERSON = w.PERSON
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[HCMEMPLOYMENT] AS e ON e.Worker = w.RECID
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MARHCMEMPDETAILS] AS ed ON e.RECID = ed.EMPLOYMENT
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[DIRPERSONUSER] AS u ON w.PERSON = u.PERSONPARTY
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[LOGISTICSELECTRONICADDRESS] AS l ON l.RECID = p.PRIMARYCONTACTEMAIL
```

My Guess is that the First and Surname can both be empty so I made the `DIRPERSONNAME` table a `LEFT JOIN` as well.

Comment: Just checked and this seems to bring back less results - I think it may be due to the inner joins as structure can be null

Comment: let me edit the query

Comment: that should do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started off with but because there can be multiple entries for the same person in the DIRPERSONNAME table, it gives me duplicated content.  Unfortunately, I can't use group as some of the fields are slightly different, which is why I went with the top 1 nested select statement